# Gmail script to autoreply to original sender from a forwarded email

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail

Trying to implement a lightweight script to run on a specific gmail account that my office uses. Typically, external people email the email address associated with that account and the autoresponder sends them a "thank you" response.

I sometimes get emails personally that should have been directed at that email address.

I'm trying to think through a script so that when I receive those emails, I can forward them to that central email address that is meant for this purpose, and then the script will auto respond from there to the original sender rather than me.

Not sure if there is a clever way to extract the original sender's email address from the forwarded message or if the original metadata listing the sender address in the header is preserved after forwarding and can be accessed directly. Any help would be appreciated.

I have some experience with Javascript. Relatively new for writing scripts for my google apps.

Comment: You can create a function to autoreply using apps script, see [example](https://gist.github.com/rboyd/5027691) but the catch here is how to know if the email received is forwarded or not? I'm not familiar about [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/), but here the link for you to be familiarized and to test how you want your code to behave. Hope this helps